# Arbitrary Groups In REST

Tags: rest

I was recently recommended a talk by [Jim Webber](https://youtu.be/aQVSzMV8DWc).
And there was a very interesting point in there.

Jim says that when you think that there is a 1-1 correspondence between rows in your database, domain objects and resources in REST service. This makes it hard when want to transact work across arability groups.

No he goes on to point that if you have say 3 users and want to update them, you do then sequentially and it is very poor because you have to track each of them and handle issues if 1 out of the 3 (or how many transactions you want occur).

He mentioned the way you should handle this is to make a resource, for all of the 3 users. Resources are cheap and infinite (you can make as many as you want) so use them. So create that resource and in a single operation put their status update.

This is an extremely interesting point to me as there have been times where I have wanted to perform an operation on multiple things that i considered to be singular.

So here is an example:
Say I have a list of users. Say 100. Users would be their own thing/resource. I want to pick x amount of users out of that list (say 10 randomly) and apply 50 points to them.
I want to apply these points to these users that have no unique connection in the domain, they are just a random group of users. a arbitrary group.

How would I create a rest endpoint/resource as Jim Webber is implying to handle this operation?

Now In my admittedly old frame of mind I would go about it making a specific resource like users/points/bulk/ (or something) and pass in a list of user id's and the points I would apply them. I would never have had the mindset of treating them as a resource, I would have just had an hacky command rest endpoint to perform it.

This point Jim has pointed out is really something I never considered and is such a change of mindset, that it would really make things cleaner.

Could someone explain this to mean and give an example to how it would look

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> He mentioned the way you should handle this is to make a resource, for all of the 3 users. Resources are cheap and infinite (you can make as many as you want) so use them. So create that resource and in a single operation put their status update.
>
> ...
>
> How would I create a rest endpoint/resource as Jim Webber is implying to handle this operation?

The basic rule of thumb here is: How would you do it on the Web? As REST is just a generalization of the interaction model the Web allowed to grow to its todays size, the same concpet that proven to be successful on the Web can (and should) be used in a REST architecture.

What is a group of resources actually?! If you think about most sport activities that are played in teams, such as football or the like, almost all players can be divided into certain groups. I.e. players of `Team A` and players of `Team B` or `all defensive players` or `all attacking players`. Each of the players is its own resource but each of the available groups is its own resource as well as we could give it a name also. We can further talk about the group instead of the individual player. Which allows us to instead of reference all of the players individually, to include all of them within a single, short statement. A statement such as "`Team A` beat the crap out of `Team B`" will most likey subsume that each of the players on `Team A` was playing better than their counterparts in the opponent team.

It is now only a matter of providing clients with the toolset to group resources together. In a typical HTML page you could i.e. have a table representation of all the active football players of this season across all teams with a checkbox to select certain players and some control element, such as a submit button, that allows you to create a group for the selected players. The backing HTML form contains not only the actual data set you could select sepcific players from and a submit button but also a target URI where the request has to be sent to as well as a request method to use. HTML by default uses `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` as representation format to send the data to the server, which knows depending on the invoked endpoint, the HTTP operation used and the media type received how to process the data accordingly.

As a new resource will be created as a consequence to the previous grouping request, the server will respond with a `201 Created` response code and a `Location` HTTP header whose value is a URI pointing to the location the newly created grouping is accessible. A client may now get redirected to that URI automatically or it can use the returned URI to invoke further operations on that resource. As the domain-model does (and probably should) not need to match a resource or affordance model, each of the invidvidual player resources as well as the team-resource may use the same database entries to present the data to the client. On updating one resource (either an individual player or the team as a whole) other resources may get influenced by this operation as well.

If you take a look at the definition of [PUT](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.4) in the HTTP specification, you can read something like this:

> A PUT request applied to the target resource can have side effects on other resources.

Due to this side-effect it is possible for an update performed via `PUT` to achive somthing similar to a partial-update:

> Partial content updates are possible by targeting a separately identified resource with state that overlaps a portion of the larger resource, or by using a different method that has been specifically defined for partial updates (for example, the PATCH method defined in [RFC5789](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789)).

I.e. if you update `Player 1` of `Team A` via `PUT` it creates as a side effect a partial-update of the state of `Team A` as this just uses the same data the data-model provides for that particular player.

In order to achive the same functionality in a REST architecture, as mentioned before, the same concepts of providing a client with structured data it can select a subset from and perform operations on that subset, such as creating a new resource for these selected elements, should be used. In contrast to the Web where HTML is dominant, the supported media-types may varry drastically in a REST architecture. Here, content-type negotiation is a very important part as this allows the server to chose the most suitable representation format that is supported by the client. Instead of using proprietary representation formats, standardized formats should be used to increase the likelihood of clients not under your control to be able to interact with your system. While there is an ongoing effort on introducing media-types that support clients with client-feedback in the form of forms similar to the ones used in HTML, there is no de-facto standard form-representation, except for HTML, yet widely accepted. There are a couple of especially JSON-based approaches, such as [hal-forms](https://rwcbook.github.io/hal-forms/), [halo+json](http://halform.herokuapp.com/), [Ion](https://ionspec.org/) or [Hydra](http://www.hydra-cg.com/), in the working, though, as mentioned, nothing that is really used widely in production.

As your acutal intention is to update a bunch of resources atomically, you could use [PATCH](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789) here as well, without the need of creating new resources, as `PATCH` is defined to perform all of the instructions atomically - either all succeed or none at all. In the spec, `PATCH` is defined similar to how patching is understood in software engineering, by having a sequence of instructions that should be applied to a resource to transform it to a desired output. [`application/json-patch+json`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902) is a representation format that is quite close to the actual definition whereas [`application/merge-patch+json`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7386) has a totally different take on it by defining default rules to apply, depending whether the request contained a modified or nullified field value. As the latter representation-format is able to only work on a single resource, the first representation-format could be used for a batch update. By targeting the collection-resource directly, [JSON Pointers](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6901) can be used to address the respective fields of the sub-resources in that collection directly.

To avoid data-loss via `PATCH` operations, due to intermediary updates between fetching the most recent state, calculating the necessary steps to apply and sending the request to the API, an optimistic locking approach should be used that is achievable via [conditional requests](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232), such as [ETag](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232#section-2.3).

While patching provides you with the capability to apply the changes atomically, I feel that grouping resources together, if they naturally form a group, such as in the player - team example, feels more common and reuses the interaction model proposed by REST also better IMO.

Comment: Thank you so much for you in depth answer. This has really helping me understand Jim's point. The analogy of players, teams and selecting players from a session is a very representation example.
Some of the parts of this answer I will admit have gone over my head because i am not quite there yet, but it has given me points to follow and next steps.

Comment: I have a comment following this answer about the actual implementation.
So I understand you can create a group resource so that you can work on these individual players as a set and treat the group as a resource. You mentioned about potentially having a table where you select a set of players. You would then submit and create the group. So this group you create, could you give me example of how this url would look and does a database table need to be created for this? Otherwise how will you be able to go back to the id of the group and put to it updating

Comment: @Matster2 Usually it is the task of the server to assign the new resource a URI. This allows a server to manage its own namespace. Whether you need a database or use some other form of persistence (i.e. a local file or similar) is an internal detail to the outside. In a relational DB you either could create a further table that defines the group and just references each member or you could add a new column to each player that assigns him to a group. The latter, however, doesn't scale well with assigning multiple groups to the same player.

Comment: @Matster2 in a NoSQL world the management of the player - group relationship is a bit more simpler, I guess. Though most HTTP server/REST frameworks require the definition of the endpoint that handles these groupings to be present before it is invoked. To my knowledge there is no dynamic assignment, other than through a plugin you add to your server, possible. And in such a case it is usually no problem to deploy a new version of the server that contains support for such functionality. Though, in a REST environment adding new features over time is explicitly possible. The appearance of a ...

Comment: @Matster2 ... new functionality should not break clients. They might not know what to do with it exactly and simply ignore it until it is taught about it, though a client should not stop working all of a sudden by introducing a new feature. As mentioned before, the form of the URI isn't of relevance here. The server should now, but the client shouldn't care as it simply invokes the URI based on some link-relation name decisions . The server, of course, has to know which mapping is invoked though so that it can reference the right group on querying it and return the right players for that group

Comment: Thank you for your response. your comment has put my mind at ease that it is ok to add a new table for this or even find an alternative storage method. Also understanding that the url is irrelevant as long as it breaks the client.

Comment: taking the request body as the last thing. is there any constraints best practices against having a url for /players/group/2131 and then in the request have an object for each player and a value I want to update for them?
e.g.
[
{
    player: 12,
    score: 29
},
{
   player: 21,
   score: 19
}...
as one of the points of this question was off of jim webbers point about mutliple transactions in 1 request/changing multiple transactions for individual resources to 1 resource tranaction

Comment: @Matster2 You should ask yourself how a client knows what a server wants? In HTML the server teaches a client on the supported elements of a resource via a form, that can be reused for updating the state as well by prefilling it with the current state. A client that supports that media-type knows the semantics of the form and the server, in case of HTML i.e., does also provide the HTTP method to use as well as the URI to send the data to. You thereby can use such a URI as proposed or use something different like `/groups/2131` or the like. It's up to you ;)

Comment: @Matster2 in regards to transactions, HTTP doesn't give any promises other than on [pipelining requests](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-6.3.2) (send a couple of requests in sequence without waiting on the response, that the server has to respond in the order it received the requests). None of the HTTP methods, other than `PATCH`, actually imply some form  of transactions. This is considered an implementation detail. While certain methods may have side-effects on other resources, this is typically not the norm but more of an exception to the rule.