# How to structure a RESTful backend API with a database?

Tags: rest

I want to make an API using REST which interacts (stores) data in a database.

While I was reading some design patterns and I came across remote facade, and the book I was reading mentions that the role of this facade is to translate the course grained methods from the remote calls into fine grained local calls, and that **it should not have any extra logic**. As an explaination, it says that the program should still work without this facade.

[Here's an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKf6H.png)

Yet I have two questions:

- Considering I also have a database, does it make sense to split the general call into specific calls for each attribute? Doesn't it make more sense to just have a general "get data" method that runs one query against the database and converts it into an usable object, to reduce the number of database calls? So instead of splitting the get address to get street, get city, get zip, make on db call for all that info.
- With all this in mind, and, in my case using golang, how should the project be structured in terms of files and functions?

  - I will have the main file with all the endpoints from the REST API, calling the controllers that handle these requests.
  - I will have a set of files that define those controllers. Are these controllers the remote facade? Should those methods not have logic in that case, and just call the equivalent local methods?
  - Should the local methods call the database directly, or should they use some sort of helper class that accesses the database?

Assuming all questions are positive, does the following structure make sense?

- Main
- Controllers
- Domain
- Database helper

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First and foremost, as [Mike Amundsen](http://amundsen.com/talks/2016-06-wsrest/2016-06-WADM.pdf) has stated

> Your data model is not your object model is not your resource model is not your affordance model

Jim Webber did say [something very similar](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc&t=1591), that by implementing a REST architecture you have an integration model, in the form of the Web, which is governed by HTTP and the other being the domain model. Resources adept and project your domain model to the world, though there is no 1:1 mapping between the data in your database and the representations you send out. A typical REST system does have many more resources than you have DB entries in your domain model.

With that being said, it is hard to give concrete advice on how you should structure your project, especially in terms of a certain framework you want to use. In regards to Robert "Uncle Bob" C. Martin on looking at the code structure, it should tell you something about the intent of the application and not about the framework[¹](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o_TH-Y78tt4&t=646s) you use. According to him [*Architecture is about intent*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o_TH-Y78tt4&t=860s). Though what you usually see is the default-structure imposed by a framework such as Maven, Ruby on Rails, ... For `golang` you should probably read through certain documentation or [blogs](https://aaf.engineering/go-web-application-structure-pt-1/) which might or might not give you some ideas.

In terms of accessing the database you might either try to follow a micro-service architecture where each service maintains their own database or you attempt something like a distributed monolith that acts as one cohesive system and shares the database among all its parts. In case you scale to the broad and a couple of parallel services consume data, i.e. in case of a message broker, you might need a distributed lock and/or queue to guarantee that the data is not consumed by multiple instances at the same time.

What you should do, however, is design your data layer in a way that it does scale well. What many developers often forget or underestimate is the benefit they can gain from caching. Links are basically used on the Web to reference from one resource to an other and giving the relation some semantic context by the utilization of well-defined link-relation names. Link relations also allow a server to control its own namespace and change URIs as needed. But URIs are not only pointers to a resource a client can invoke but also keys for a cache. Caching can take place on multiple locations. On the server side to avoid costly calculations or look ups on the client side to avoid sending requests out in general or on intermediary hops which allow to take away pressure from heavily requested servers. Fielding made [caching even a constraint](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_4) that needs to be respected.

In regards to what attributes you should create queries for is totally dependent on the use case you attempt to depict. In case of the address example given it does make sense to return the address information all at once as the street or zip code is rarely queried on its own. If the address is part of some user or employee data it is more vague whether to return that information as part of the user or employee data or just as a link that should be queried on its own as part of a further request. What you return may also depend on the capabilities of the media-type client and your service agree upon (content-type negotiation).

If you implement something like a [grouping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56473938/arbitrary-groups-in-rest/56481773) for i.e. some football players and certain categories they belong to, such as their teams and whether they are offense or defense players, you might have a `Team A` resource that includes all of the players as embedded data. Within the DB you could have either an own table for teams and references to the respective player or the team could just be a column in the player table. We don't know and a client usually doesn't bother as well. From a design perspective you should however be aware of the benefits and consequences of including all the players at the same time in regards to providing links to the respective player or using a mixed approach of presenting some base data and a link to learn further details.

The latter approach is probably the most sensible way as this gives a client enough information to determine whether more detailed data is needed or not. If needed a simple GET request to the provided URI is enough, which might be served by a cache and thus never reach the actual server at all. The first approach has for sure the disadvantage that it doesn't reuse caching optimally and may return way more data then actually needed. The approach to include links only may not provide enough information forcing the client to perform a follow-up request to learn data about the team member. But as mentioned before, you as the service designer decide which URIs or queries are returned to the client and thus can design your system and data model accordingly.

In general what you do in a REST architecture is providing  a client with choices. It is good practice to design the overall interaction flow as [a state machine](https://nordicapis.com/designing-a-true-rest-state-machine/) which is traversed through receiving requests and returning responses. As REST uses the same interaction model as the Web, it probably feels more natural to design the whole system as if you'd implement it for the Web and then apply the design to your REST system.

Whether controllers should contain business logic or not is primarily an opinionated question. As [Jim Webber](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc&t=191s) correctly stated, HTTP, which is the de-facto transport layer of REST, is an

> application protocol whose application domain is the transfer of documents over a network. That is what HTTP does. It moves documents around. ... HTTP is an application protocol, but it is NOT YOUR application protocol.

He further points out that you have to narrow HTTP into a domain application protocol and trigger business activities as a side-effect of moving documents around the network. So, it's the side-effect of moving documents over the network that triggers your business logic. There is no straight rule whether to include business logic in your controller or not, but usually you try to keep the business logic in yet their own layer, i.e. as a service that you just invoke from within the controller. That allows to test the business logic without the need of the controller and thus without the need of a real HTTP request.

While this answer can't provide more detailed information, partly due to the broad nature of the question itself, I hope I could shed some light in what areas you should put in some thoughts and that your data model is not necessarily your resource or affordance model.

Comment: I wasn't expecting such a detailed answer at all. It was really insightful and although I didn't understand it all because of my lack of knowledge in the area, it was very useful. The link you provided for the golang blog also provides answers for the questions I had. Thank you!